# Como passa dois parâmetros no Ng-click Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

```
 <button class="btn btn-conf-t btn-deletar" ng-click="deleteCategory(cat.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

Aqui eu apenas passo um parâmetro, é possível passar `ng-click="deleteCategory(cat.id, cat.nome)"` ?

Answer (score 1):

É só separa com vírgula, desta forma:

```
deleteCategory(cat.id, cat.name)
```

Ficando desta forma:

```
<button class="btn btn-conf-t btn-deletar" ng-click="deleteCategory(cat.id, cat.name)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

Lembrando que a sua função `deleteCategory` deve ser alterada para receber os dois valores.

Caso queira executar duas funções é só fazer a chamada das duas dentro de `deleteCategory`.

**Veja um pequeno exemplo:**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;
  $scope.somar = function(val, val2) {
    $scope.count = val + val2;
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click="somar(2, 5)">OK</button>
  <p>Resultado: {{count}} </p>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ...é possível passar ng-click="deleteCategory(cat.id, cat.nome)"?

Sim, e possível. Entretanto, seu modelo de eventos talvez fique ainda mais resistente se você passar a *referência do objeto*:

```
ng-click="deleteCategory(cat)"
```

Dentro de seu *controller* você pode então ler as propriedades do objeto referenciado:

```
$scope.deleteCategory = function (cat) {
    console.log(cat.id, cat.nome);
}
```